# How to DRY S3 Buckets with different ACLs and global tags?

Tags: terragrunt

the following file structure:

```
.
├── account.hcl
├── prod
│   ├── env.hcl
│   └── s3
│       └── terragrunt.hcl
├── region.hcl
└── stage
    ├── env.hcl
    └── s3
        └── terragrunt.hcl
```

in prod and stage the env.hcl's are the same which is not DRY:

```
locals {
  environment = "prod"
  project     = "foo"
}
```

but how I'm able to combine the tags with the environment names if I would use some globaltags.hcl inside my root folder (where account.hcl lives)?

inside terragrunt.hcl there's the the variable collector from the examples like:

```
locals {
  # Automatically load environment-level variables
  environment_vars = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl"))

  # Extract out common variables for reuse
  env = local.environment_vars.locals.environment
}
```

and the inputs for the different bucket names like:

```
inputs = {
  bucketnames   = [
                   "foo-${local.env}",
                   "bar-${local.env}",
                   "baz-${local.env}"
                  ]
  tags          = local.environment_vars.locals
}
```

here I have no idea how to use different acl settings for each bucket?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for "global" tags is:
in your root folder you're using common.hcl wich includes your tags

```
locals {
  Project = "OneApp"
  Foo     = "Bar"
}
```

under the root folder you're defining different environments via folders like "dev", "stage", etc.
within every of those folders/environments you should place env.hcl e.g:

```
locals {
  environment = "prod"
}
```

and now on your module-level (root/dev/s3/terragrunt.hcl) just include the following lines.
into your local-block:

```
common = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("common.hcl"))
```

and in your input-block:

```
tags = merge(local.common.locals,local.environment_vars.locals,)
```

now you're able to run terragrunt on your module level but also from your root level (via terragrunt run-all). it will go through all child-folders/environments and combine your global tags with the environment tag.